# Angular change mat-select width dynamically based on length of selected element

Tags: angular, width

I am atempting to solve this problem to set the width of the dropdown dynamically when a long string is selected.
Tried to set width:"auto" or fit-content but seem not to work.

Hoping somebody can help me out here.
Stackblitz link is bellow:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-testing?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: so do you want to increase width of mat-select when some-long-string is being selected ?

Comment: correct and the width should be based on the length of the string

Comment: https://angular-mat-select-testing-jh8uwn.stackblitz.io/ check this..

Comment: yes exactly this looks great, how did you do it?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-testing-jh8uwn?file=src%2Fstyles.scss here is code for the demo

Comment: why does it not work when I copy the scss part into the app.component.scss? like here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-testing?file=src/app/app.component.scss

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-testing-jh8uwn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.scss here is app.component.scss version . You simple need to add `::ng-deep` before class name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working demo in this demo [StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-testing-jh8uwn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.scss)

You need to add below css code in app.component.scss..

```
::ng-deep .auto-width {
    .mat-form-field {
       width: auto !important;
    }
    .mat-select-value {
       max-width: 100%;
       min-width: 100%;
    }
 }
```

In order to detect and apply style to deep level component you need to add `::ng-deep` before class name .auto-width. and other option is you can add .auto-width class inside style.scss file so that every component will use this global css configuration.

Comment: how come same approach wont work under Angular12? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular12-material-mat-select-dynamic-size?file=src/app/app.component.css

Comment: its not about because of angular 12 version, its because of .css structure. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular12-material-mat-select-dynamic-size-dhadqc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css